# Html.EditorFor sorted children of an Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, editorfor

**In an MVC Razor View, how do I display an ordered list of child items within an EF model using the Html.EditorFor method?**

To edit a list of child items (with several fields) from a parent Entity Framework model, I use the standard syntax (table header and footer elements omitted for clarity) as follows.

```
<tbody>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ServiceCheckItems)
</tbody>
```

This requires an edit View in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ServiceCheckItem.cshtml. Note that **ServiceCheckItems** is the entity framework child collection in the parent and **ServiceCheckItem** is an instance of one child item, for which the editor template name must match.

Here is a simplified example of the editor view. Every property is either rendered in an editor or a hidden field to ensure child items can be recreated for post back

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CheckType)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @* We must put every non-EditorFor field into a hidden to be remembered for post-back and the next render back to the client *@
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CheckType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SequenceNumber)
    </td>
</tr>
```

This approach works well and I can post the parent model back to various actions with all of the related child items still attached, render the model back to the client again so the user can perform more work.

However, the child items have an ordering column and should be displayed in that order. I couldn't find a simple answer as to how to present the list ordered by this field.

The model is based on an Entity Framework (dynamic class) which is returned using the traditional approach.

```
return await _db.SomeTable.FindAsync(id);
```

The child items either exist in the database or are added in an **Action** when a user first creates them. These are rendered back to the client for the user to edit their content.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiment, I found a solution that works. In a code section of the view, I provide a sorted version of the child items that the editor is expecting

```
ICollection<ServiceCheckItem> ServiceCheckItems = Model.ServiceCheckItems.OrderBy(i => i.SequenceNumber).ToList();
```

The editor is then presented with the model as follows. Note that the name **ServiceCheckItems** must match the list of child items that the editor view is expecting, otherwise the rendered children will have the wrong prefix name and, although correctly reassembled for post-back, will not match the list name of the parent and will not be attached.

```
<tbody>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => ServiceCheckItems)
</tbody>
```

I hope this helps other folks. If you have a better answer I'd love to see it.

Comment: Why not just do `@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ServiceCheckItems.OrderBy(i => i.SequenceNumber))` ?

Comment: Doesn't work - complains of not being a lambda expression

Comment: Cast it to a list or array.